# Changing Number of Particles in amcl ROS Package for Turtlebot Localization

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the turtlebot stage simulator

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373516/hello,-i%27m-using-amcl-ros-package-in-order-to-localize-turtlebot-globally-can-any-one-tell-how-can-i-change-the-default-number-of-particles-because-it-seems-that-the-max-number-is-2000/) by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2021-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the [amcl docs](https://wiki.ros.org/amcl) you see there is a `max_particles` parameter. Find the launch files that launches amcl and change that parameters default value.

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2021-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on 2021-03-30**:
Thanks alot.